# Java to Node.js AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding Encryption

Tags: node.js, encryption, aes

I have the following encrypt function in JAVA. I am trying to write the same encryption in Node.js using cipher from crypto. But, the output is not the same. It is using the same key and input.

#### JAVA

```
public static String encrypt(String input, String key) {
    byte[] crypted = null;
    try {
        SecretKeySpec skey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skey);
        crypted = cipher.doFinal(input.getBytes());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
    String result = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(crypted));
    return result.replace("+", "-");
}
```

Sample output: 0HCkcjWj/PoCZ4ZUFJARs/m4kstigMFk8dQnT0uNhog= (44 characters)

#### Node.js

```
encrypt = (input, key) => { 
    const algorithm = 'aes-128-cbc';   
    key = crypto.scryptSync(key, 'salt', 16);       
    const iv = Buffer.alloc(16, 0);
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);
    cipher.setAutoPadding(true);
    let encrypted = cipher.update(input, 'utf8', 'base64');
    encrypted += cipher.final('base64');
    return encrypted.replace('+','-');
}
```

Sample output: ZHtEbAhrIo7vWOjdMNgW6Q== (24 characters)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide the input message and key so we can compare not just the ciphertext?

Answer (score 3):

So that the NodeJS code is functionally identical to the Java code, in the NodeJS code:

- ECB mode must be used instead of CBC mode:

  ```
  const algorithm = 'aes-128-ecb';
  ...
  //const iv = Buffer.alloc(16, 0); // remove
  const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key, null);
  ```

  Note, however, that ECB doesn't use an IV, is generally insecure and should therefore not be used, [[1]](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/20946).
  Better alternatives are CBC mode (confidentiality) or GCM mode (confidentiality, authenticity/integrity), [[2]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_(CBC)), [[3]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode).
- No key derivation function may be applied [[4]](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_scryptsync_password_salt_keylen_options), i.e. the following line must be removed:

  ```
  key = crypto.scryptSync(key, 'salt', 16);
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your detail explanation. However, the output still the same 24 characters instead of 44 which I got in Java. Did I miss something in my js code?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue using my _own_ data for plaintext and key. Please post an example, i.e. plaintext, key and the results of both codes, to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Furthermore: The _different lengths_ of the ciphertexts are an indication that _different plaintexts_ were encrypted (at least when applying the posted codes). Therefore recheck whether the data used (plaintext and key) are actually identical.

Comment: Could also be an encoding error. There are plenty in the original code after all; just `getBytes` is never a good idea (especially when it comes to keys, but that's unrelated to the size of the ciphertext). Unrelated: it still cracks me up that you have to use `createCipheriv` instead of `createCipher` to implement ECB mode.

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes - Yes, a different encoding would also be a plausible explanation for the remaining problem, which could probably be more easily revealed with a concrete example from the OP. With the current code it's unfortunately not reproducible at this point (assuming the same data/encoding).